# Can't load image in xna

Tags: xna

I am begginer in xna,i ma trying to load a image,but its not working ,throwing an exception,file not found,i have tried everything surf every where,alot of people asking that ques,can't find answer please help,i m in great trouble here is the code

```
    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        mytexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("gray");
        myrectangle = new Rectangle(100, 100, 40, 40);

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(mytexture, myrectangle , Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

image is added in content

Comment: You need to provide more details: What exception is it throwing, what file can't it find? Which function is the error in?

Comment: Have you added an image with the `AssetName` "gray" to your content project?

Comment: IS the root folder of the contentloader set?

Comment: exception is content load eception was unhandled,and in detail image not found is written,prblem is with image loading only,yup i added image with gray

Comment: .png image file,i am trying to load,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either the file has been removed or moved, and is no longer able to be found by your Content project.

Look at the list of images you have under your Content project.  It is quite possible that you do not have one called gray in the root.  If it is there, there are a few things you can check:

1. If it is in a folder, you need to match it up with your
   Content.Load(@"FOLDERNAME/gray")
2. Ensure it is all lowercase like in your Content.Load directive
3. Make sure the file exists.  If it is listed there, try to open it.

Comment: it is listed in content,when clicked it opens in graphic designer type page

Comment: it is not in the folder and has perfect match of name

Answer (score 0):

thanks every one,i found solution and its a really weird one,i just make a new project,copy over everything , i change nothing but one works one didn't,anyway thanks a lot